# How to check whether request is going to an method with [Authorize] attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have WebAPI **Controller** which derives from **BaseController** which derives from `AspNetCore's` `Controller`

I'd want to load `User` from database whenever he's going into endpoint which requires being `[Authorize]`

This is my code where condition in that `if` is pseudo code because I cannot figure out how to check whether this request requires authorization or it doesn't

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    protected readonly DatabaseContext _context;
    protected readonly User _user;

    public DefaultController(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        if (HttpContext.Request.RequiresAuthorization) // pseudo code
        {
            var id = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            _user = _context.Users.Find(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I'd want to avoid loading user on every request, even when he does not need to authorize and can be not logged in there.

Is it possible to achieve kinda "globally", so `BaseController` which every other controller derives from?

Comment: Why don't you just use the [Authorize] attribute on your controller class or your specific action?

Comment: @chrillelundmark it makes a lot of sense, but I'd have to write e.g two controllers for the same thing. I'll consider that because it is very simple, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MvcOptions.Filters` to register your authorization filter globally.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 { 
      services.AddMvc(options =>
      {
           options.Filters.Add(typeof(AuthorizationFilter));
      });
 }
```

Since you have the requirement to connect a database, I would suggest, to create a custom `AuthorizationFilter` by extending `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter`

```
public class AuthorizationFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    //use constructor to inject required dependencies

    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
         //Move your custom logic here
    }
}
```